# Can the comment writing box be in monospace font?

Tags: feature-request, comments, markdown

Comments are used to clarify posts or ask for more information.
They also support a very small sample of Markdown, to allow for the addition of links, bold, italics, and code font.

I would like to propose that the comment text field editor be in monospaced font, the same as the asking and answering text field, with the exception that a toolbar is not provided.

This will greatly help with organizing our comments, because editing comments in the default font may make users think that Markdown isn't accepted in comments, when really it is.

Comment: Yes, `code markup` is possible in comments using the ` mark

Comment: Markdown [help](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help)

Comment: No, I mean that while creating your comment, the comment editor is in a code font.

Comment: You can actually change that locally, although I don't know how to do it off the top of my head.

Comment: Please get back to me with more information about this and post it as an answer. Thank you!

Comment: You just need to get the following into your CSS (for example using `GM_addStyle()` in Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey): `.comment-form>form textarea {font-family: monospace;}`